# Setencia if no funciona

Tags: php, variables, condiciones, session

Hola gente tengo ese código if:

```
$DifineUser = "admin";
$DifinePass = "admin";
$DifineUserSis = "sistemas";
$DifinePassSis = "sistemas";

if ($user === $DifineUser && $pass === $DifinePass) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
header("Location: home.php");
} else{
header("Location: entraragain.php");
$error = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
}
```

Y luego abajo el otro if

```
if ($user === $DifineUserSis && $pass === $DifinePassSis) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
header("Location: /rrhh/sistemas/home.php");
} else{
header("Location: entraragain.php");
$error = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
}
```

Resulta que se dejo un solo if me lleva a la pagina, pero si dejo los dos if me toma solo el ultimo if.

No se donde estaría el problema, en teoría tendría que respectar los if, si son variables distintas o no?

Aclarando que el pass y user admin, admin es solo como prueba.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en tu primer bloque si se cumplen las condiciones reenvías al usuario a la pagina de destino, con lo cual la actual pagina ya no es donde corre el código sino la destino, prueba inviertiendo los bloques y te encontraras con el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola podrias hacer algo mas limpio definidiendo otra variable en donde indiques el tipo de usuario y dependiendo el tipo de usuario lo redirigas algo asi

```
if($user != $DifineUser && $pass != $DifinePass){
     header("Location: entraragain.php");
    $error = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
}

$url_redirect = $type_user == 'Default' ? '/rrhh/sistemas/home.php' : 'home.php; 
header("Location: " . $url_redirect);
```

En este pongo un solo if en donde valido que la contraseña y password y en un if ternario valido el tipo de usuario dependiendo el tipo de usuario redirecciono a donde tiene que if. Solo si te faltaria definir el que tipo de usuario va usar que.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que al invocarse la función [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) no detiene el proceso de ejecución, sino que simplemente establece un encabezado de respuesta.

Al ejecutarse tu código, el proceso entra en algunas de las condición del *"primer bloque"*, pero! no se detiene, el proceso continua, se procesa el *"segundo bloque"* lo que provoca que se sobrescriba el encabezado enviado previamente.

#### Solución:

Siempre que realices una redirección utilizando `header` debes a continuación terminar el proceso de ejecución utilizando, por ejemplo, [`exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php)

**Ejemplo:**

```
if ($user === $DifineUser && $pass === $DifinePass) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
} else{
    header("Location: entraragain.php");
    $error = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
    exit;
}
// ... resto del código
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas asignando una condicionante a la variable `$user` antes de proceder al siguiente bloque de codigo, puedes validarlo de la siguiente manera en el mismo bloque utilizando `elseif` de la siguiente manera

```
session_start();
$DifineUser = "admin";
$DifinePass = "admin";
$DifineUserSis = "sistemas";
$DifinePassSis = "sistemas";

if ($user === $DifineUser && $pass === $DifinePass) {
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    header("Location: home.php");
} elseif ($user === $DifineUser && $pass === $DifinePass) {
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    header("Location: /rrhh/sistemas/home.php");
} else{
    header("Location: entraragain.php");
    $error = "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
}
```